# Why when I add new recipe instead of new recipe, appears the recipe that are already in the list ?So new recipe should appear on the screen

Tags: swiftui

TabBar.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("home", systemImage: "house")
                }
            
            CategoryView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Categories", systemImage: "square.fill.text.grid.1x2")
                }
            
            NewRecipeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("New", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            
            FavoritesView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Favorites", systemImage: "heart")
                }
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("home", systemImage: "gear")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

RecipeModel.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
    
    case breakfast = "Breakfast"
    case soup = "Soup"
    case salad = "Salad"
    case appetizer = "Appetizer"
    case main = "Main"
    case side = "Side"
    case dessert = "Dessert"
    case snack = "Snack"
    case drink = "Drink"
}
struct Recipe: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let image: String
    let description: String
    let ingredients: String
    let directions: String
    let category: Category.RawValue
    let datePublished: String
    let url: String
}

extension Recipe {
    static let all: [Recipe] = [
        
              Recipe(name: "Broccoli  Salad",
                     image: "https://therecipecritic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/greekbroccolisalad-667x1000.jpg",
                     description: "Greek Broccoli Pasta Salad combines tender fusilli pasta with fresh vegetables and a tangy herb dressing. This is the perfect dish to serve with grilled meats, or pack for a picnic or barbecue!",
                     ingredients: "1 pound rotini pasta,\n 4 cups broccoli florets cut into 1-inch pieces (8 ounces),\n 1 ½ cups cherry tomatoes cut in half,\n 1 cup diced green bell pepper 1/2-inch dice,\n1 ½ cup diced red onion ¼-inch dice,\n ½ cup kalamata olives sliced,\n ¼ cup crumbled Feta cheese.",
                     directions: "1. Bring a large pot of water to a boil and add the pasta and cook according to package directions.\n 2. The last two minutes add in the broccoli. Drain and rinse in cold water.\n 3. In a large serving bowl toss together pasta, broccoli, tomatoes, bell pepper, onion, and olives.",
                     category: "Salad",
                     datePublished: "2021-7-29",
                     url: "https://therecipecritic.com/greek-broccoli-pasta-salad/"),
              Recipe(name: "Pasta Salad",
                     image: "https://therecipecritic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/greekbroccolisalad-667x1000.jpg",
                     description: "Greek Broccoli Pasta Salad combines tender fusilli pasta with fresh vegetables and a tangy herb dressing. This is the perfect dish to serve with grilled meats, or pack for a picnic or barbecue!",
                     ingredients: "1 pound rotini pasta,\n 4 cups broccoli florets cut into 1-inch pieces (8 ounces),\n 1 ½ cups cherry tomatoes cut in half,\n 1 cup diced green bell pepper 1/2-inch dice,\n1 ½ cup diced red onion ¼-inch dice,\n ½ cup kalamata olives sliced,\n ¼ cup crumbled Feta cheese.",
                     directions: "1. Bring a large pot of water to a boil and add the pasta and cook according to package directions.\n 2. The last two minutes add in the broccoli. Drain and rinse in cold water.\n 3. In a large serving bowl toss together pasta, broccoli, tomatoes, bell pepper, onion, and olives.",
                     category: "Dessert",
                     datePublished: "2021-7-28",
                     url: "https://therecipecritic.com/greek-broccoli-pasta-salad/"),
              Recipe(name: "Broccoli Pasta Salad",
                     image: "https://therecipecritic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/greekbroccolisalad-667x1000.jpg",
                     description: "Greek Broccoli Pasta Salad combines tender fusilli pasta with fresh vegetables and a tangy herb dressing. This is the perfect dish to serve with grilled meats, or pack for a picnic or barbecue!",
                     ingredients: "1 pound rotini pasta,\n 4 cups broccoli florets cut into 1-inch pieces (8 ounces),\n 1 ½ cups cherry tomatoes cut in half,\n 1 cup diced green bell pepper 1/2-inch dice,\n1 ½ cup diced red onion ¼-inch dice,\n ½ cup kalamata olives sliced,\n ¼ cup crumbled Feta cheese.",
                     directions: "1. Bring a large pot of water to a boil and add the pasta and cook according to package directions.\n 2. The last two minutes add in the broccoli. Drain and rinse in cold water.\n 3. In a large serving bowl toss together pasta, broccoli, tomatoes, bell pepper, onion, and olives.",
                     category: "Snacks",
                     datePublished: "2020-7-27",
                     url: "https://therecipecritic.com/greek-broccoli-pasta-salad/"),
              Recipe(name: "Greek Salad",
                     image: "https://therecipecritic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/greekbroccolisalad-667x1000.jpg",
                     description: "Greek Broccoli Pasta Salad combines tender fusilli pasta with fresh vegetables and a tangy herb dressing. This is the perfect dish to serve with grilled meats, or pack for a picnic or barbecue!",
                     ingredients: "1 pound rotini pasta,\n 4 cups broccoli florets cut into 1-inch pieces (8 ounces),\n 1 ½ cups cherry tomatoes cut in half,\n 1 cup diced green bell pepper 1/2-inch dice,\n1 ½ cup diced red onion ¼-inch dice,\n ½ cup kalamata olives sliced,\n ¼ cup crumbled Feta cheese.",
                     directions: "1. Bring a large pot of water to a boil and add the pasta and cook according to package directions.\n 2. The last two minutes add in the broccoli. Drain and rinse in cold water.\n 3. In a large serving bowl toss together pasta, broccoli, tomatoes, bell pepper, onion, and olives.",
                     category: "Drinks",
                     datePublished: "2022-7-26",
                     url: "https://therecipecritic.com/greek-broccoli-pasta-salad/"),
    ]
}
```

RecipeView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct RecipeView: View {
    var recipe: Recipe
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: recipe.image)) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                      .scaledToFill()
                      .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
                      .clipped()
            } placeholder: {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.7))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            .frame(height: 400)
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(.gray).opacity(0.3), Color.gray]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
           
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                Text(recipe.name)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                    if !recipe.description.isEmpty {
                        Text(recipe.description)
                    }
                    
                    if !recipe.ingredients.isEmpty {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                            Text("Ingredients")
                                .font(.headline)
                            
                            Text(recipe.ingredients)
                        }
                    }
                    if !recipe.directions.isEmpty {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                            Text("Directions")
                                .font(.headline)
                            
                            Text(recipe.directions)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
    }
}
```

RecipeCard.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct RecipeCard: View {
    var recipe: Recipe
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: recipe.image)) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                        Text(recipe.name).font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 3, x: 0, y: 0)
                            .frame(maxWidth: 136)
                            .padding()
                    }
            } placeholder: {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.7))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                        Text(recipe.name)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 3, x: 0, y: 0)
                            .frame(maxWidth: 136)
                            .padding()
                    }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 160, height: 217, alignment: .top)
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(.gray).opacity(0.3), Color.gray]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous))
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 15, x: 0, y: 10)
    }
}
```

RecipeList.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct RecipeList: View {
    var recipes: [Recipe]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("\(recipes.count) \(recipes.count > 1 ? "recipes" : "recipe")")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .opacity(0.7)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 160), spacing: 15)], spacing: 15) {
                ForEach(recipes) { recipe in
                    NavigationLink(destination: RecipeView(recipe: recipe)) {
                        RecipeCard(recipe: recipe)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.top)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

HomeView.swift

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var recipesVM: RecepiesViewModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                RecipeList(recipes: recipesVM.recipes)
            }
            .navigationTitle("My recipes")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
            .environmentObject(RecepiesViewModel())
    }
}
```

RecipesViewModel.swift

```
import Foundation

class RecepiesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var recipes: [Recipe] = []
    
    init() {
        recipes = Recipe.all
    }
    
    func addRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
        recipes.append(recipe)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddRecipeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var recipesVM: RecepiesViewModel
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var selectedCategory = Category.main
    @State private var description = ""
    @State private var ingredients = ""
    @State private var directions = ""
    @State private var navigateTorecipe = false
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Name")) {
                    TextField("Recipe Name", text: $name)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Category")) {
                    Picker("Category", selection: $selectedCategory) {
                        ForEach(Category.allCases) { category in
                            Text(category.rawValue)
                                .tag(category)
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.menu)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Description")) {
                    TextEditor(text: $description)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Ingredients")) {
                    TextEditor(text: $ingredients)
                }
            Section(header: Text("Directions")) {
                TextEditor(text: $directions)
            }
        }
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                       dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Label("Cancel", systemImage: "xmark")
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem {
                    NavigationLink(isActive: $navigateTorecipe) {
                        RecipeView(recipe: recipesVM.recipes.sorted{ $0.datePublished > $1.datePublished }[0])
                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    } label: {
                        Button {
                            saveRecipe()
                            navigateTorecipe = true
                        } label: {
                            Label("Done", systemImage: "checkmark")
                                .labelStyle(.iconOnly )
                        }
                    }
                    .disabled(name.isEmpty)
                }
            })
            .navigationTitle("New Recipe")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
      }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
  }
}

struct AddRecipeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddRecipeView()
            .environmentObject(RecepiesViewModel())
    }
}

extension AddRecipeView {
    private func saveRecipe() {
        let now = Date()
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
        
        let datePublished = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
        print(datePublished)
        
        let recipe = Recipe(name: name, image: "", description: description, ingredients: ingredients, directions: directions, category: selectedCategory.rawValue, datePublished: datePublished, url: "")
        recipesVM.addRecipe(recipe: recipe)
    }
}
```

New Recipe.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewRecipeView: View {
    @State private var showAddRecipe = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button("Add recipe mannually", action: {
                showAddRecipe = true
            })
                .navigationTitle("New Recipe")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddRecipe) {
            AddRecipeView()
        }
    }
}

struct NewRecipeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewRecipeView()
    }
}
```

[Add a new recipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hizi3.png)
[new recipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrEZR.jpg)

[But the newly added recipe appears in My recipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrEZR.jpg)

[another recipe that pops up instead of newly added one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTxBd.png)
Why when I add new recipe instead of new recipe, appears the recipe that are already in the list ?
It supposed to pop up the recipe that I add.So new recipe should appear on the screen

May be NavigationLink or sth?

How can I remove this error?

Comment: Can you de word your question? It is confusing and not clear.

Comment: You mean you don't understand the question?

Comment: Where is the code for My recipes?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You are saying that your code shows the new recipe and that you expected behavior AND issue is that it shows the new recipe. It doesn't sound like there is a problem. Some rewording might describe your issue a little better. We also need a full example so we can troubleshoot.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Note that with `.sheet(...)`, you
 need to explicitly pass the `environmentObject`,
 such as `AddRecipeView().environmentObject(recipesVM)`

Comment: you don't seem to use `NewRecipeView` anywhere. Where do you call this? You will probably have to use `@EnvironmentObject var recipesVM: RecepiesViewModel` in `NewRecipeView` to pass it to the `.sheet(...)` as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: I use NewRecipeView in a TabBar

Comment: As I said in my comments, you need to pass `RecepiesViewModel` to `NewRecipeView`, then to 
`AddRecipeView().environmentObject(recipesVM)`, because `AddRecipeView` refers to it. 
In your `TabBar` view you do not pass `RecepiesViewModel` to `NewRecipeView`.
Similarly for `HomeView` and all the other views that needs `RecepiesViewModel`. See also: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views